# Remove advise backlight from code

Tags: intellij-idea

Okey, here is an example:
IDEA advise me something like at screenshot:[image: advice]

Ок, I have read it and think that all is correct. So, how can I now move out backlight from line 39? It is divert me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your cursor on the assignment. Hit Alt-Enter (MacOS keyboard layout). Select "Inspection 'Suspicious variable ...'. Choose "Suppress for statement" or "Suppress for method".